# What's the advantage of using an ObjectId instead of a plain String?

Tags: mongodb

What is the advantage to using an ObjectId instead of, say, a UUID as a plain String?

Comment: @ich Flagged. You're being obnoxious. Has it really been discussed trillions of times? No. Hyperbole and sarcasm isn't welcome around here. If it's a dupe, link to the dupe and vote to close. If you can't find the dupe, keep your obnoxious opinion to yourself.

Comment: @ich I actually searched for "mongodb objectid" (without quotes) here on SO, skimmed the results from the first page and didn't find the answer to my question. Is you have a helpful link, please share.

Comment: I don't understand the rage from @jcollum comment, maybe the question/comment was edited/deleted in between but I see nothing wrong with the question. If it is a duplicate, please flag it as so instead. (Even if the question is several years old, I feel I still have to write this)

Comment: Well Cyril I have no idea what was going on. I assume the obnoxious comments were deleted.

Answer (score 18):

An ObjectId is binary, and thus takes up less space. ObjectIds also have the sorting factor--they will end up being in insertion order (or very close), while remaining unique. The sorting can be good for some things, but unwanted for others (like shard keys). You can also extract the timestamp (second resolution) from an ObjectId, which can be convenient.

Aside from that, I would say there's not much difference.