# The only difference between an ObjectID and the string version is that it's smaller?

Tags: mongodb

Why does MongoDB use `ObjectID` instead of a string version of it?

Everything is just as possible with the string version of it (date, ordering, etc) and it makes it easier to transport to the client. Is it just that it's smaller?

Thanks for any info!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405720/whats-the-advantage-of-using-an-objectid-instead-of-a-plain-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why mongoDB uses objectID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560928/why-mongodb-uses-objectid)

Comment: So the only difference between an ObjectID and the string version is that it's smaller? Everything else is possible with the string (date, etc)

Comment: ObjectId also holds a timestamp http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/

Comment: @Kostis, the string version holds a timestamp as well.

Comment: it is also faster to compare a binary edition, and to extract parts of it

Comment: @Sammaye this is the start of the answer I'm looking for. Can you provide any more detail for mongo use cases?

Comment: Tbh that was the only part that wasn't mentioned in the related question, other than that you could use the string version for everything, from sharding to replication, it just comes down to getting that extra bit of performance, on a large distributed network of sharded data it becomes a huge bit of performane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember someone who used to code conditionals with strings, eg if x == "red" then... and so on. Said it was clearer and easier to understand, yet strangely it performed quite badly.

Its time like this I think everyone should be taught C programming so they'd understand what happens under the covers when you write programs.

Edit: performance in these cases is about the size of the item being compared. If you have a value that fits into a single fetch instruction, the CPU can do a compare in 1 instruction, but if you have something that requires multiple fetches, it has to compare each one in turn. Now, if a string is used, the CPU has to compare each character to see if they are all the same (or stop when it gets to the first difference). That's massively slower than a single comparison. An ID value like the one used in MongoDB is actually a hash, (a 12-byte hash hash at that) and on most CPUs nowadays, a 64-bit value can be compared in 1 instruction. Its all about how the memory is read, and how the CPU can process it. CPUs are ultimately very simple things, they just do a few simple things very fast.

Mongo's hash is 12 bytes: which is unfortunately 96 bits so it doesn't fit into a single 64-bit CPU value, so it can end up as 2 compares. This is still much better than a string - even a 12 byte string will require 12 compares, and I think modern CPUs have 128-bit registers for certain comparison operations, so if the CPU has the right SSE registers, it'll be a single compare op anyway.

I think they chose to pack all those values in as they wanted the time to be included in the hash, along with process and machine ids to make it unique in case 2 machines happened to write simultaneously.

Also unfortunately, they use 4 bytes for the time component, which won't be too useful after the 2038 deadline for 4-byte time values, but it'll still be unique for practical purposes.

It might be possible to do faster string comparisons, using SSE4 for example, but they require the string to have certain restrictions - eg. they must be aligned properly, have a length in multiples of 16 bytes, and not cross page boundaries.

Comment: Isn't this a comment?

Comment: This is actually the perfect time to just explain it instead of being snarky. This is a question after all..

Comment: @boom well fair enough, but I was feeling sarky. I thought the question would already be closed.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Thanks for the edit, this is the answer I was looking for. Answers to supposed "duplicate" questions never even touched on this difference.

Comment: @gbjbaanb I have one follow up question for you. If I need the ObjectIDs to be strings in other parts of my application. Is it better to store the `_id`s as strings in mongo or convert from string to ObjectID before every query? (I know you don't have all the information but what would be your general guidance?)

Comment: @boom I'd store them as the native objectID type. Its only a simple structure. I'd only convert it to a string to display it. The cost of conversion *on each query* could be more than I'd want (that depends on a lot, of course). Spend a little time figuring out how to handle the objectid natively before using its string (or BSON serialisation type). See [the doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) for some, limited, help.