# NodeJS with mongoDB JSONFormat issue

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to NodeJS and MongoDb. I am facing an issue on jsonObject.

**Step 1:** I have installed NodeJS and MongoDB sucessfully in my ubuntu 16.04 system.

**Step 2:** I created the all server setup with package.json file in my project folder.

**Step 3:** I created the server.js file Like below.

**server.js** File

```
    express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./api/routes/todoListRoutes');
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Task = require('./api/models/todoListModels'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Tododb');
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    routes(app);
    app.listen(port);
    console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

then I created Model file for storing the records.

**todoListModels.js**

```
    'use strict';
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


    var TaskSchema = new Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        Required: 'Kindly enter the name of the task'
      },
      Created_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      },
      status: {
        type: [{
          type: String,
          enum: ['pending', 'ongoing', 'completed']
        }],
        default: ['pending']
      }
    },{ versionKey: false }//Updated);

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Tasks', TaskSchema);
```

**todoListRoutes.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
  var todoList = require('../controllers/todoListController');
  app.route('/tasks').get(todoList.list_all_tasks).post(todoList.create_a_task);
  app.route('/tasks/:taskId').get(todoList.read_a_task).put(todoList.update_a_task).delete(todoList.delete_a_task);
};
```

**todoListController.js**

```
'use strict';


mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Task = mongoose.model('Tasks');

exports.list_all_tasks = function(req, res) {
  Task.find({}, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
};

exports.create_a_task = function(req, res) {
  var new_task = new Task(req.body);
  new_task.save(function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
};


exports.read_a_task = function(req, res) {
  Task.findById(req.params.taskId, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
};


exports.update_a_task = function(req, res) {
  Task.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.taskId, req.body, {new: true}, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
};


exports.delete_a_task = function(req, res) {
  Task.remove({
    _id: req.params.taskId
  }, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({ message: 'Task successfully deleted' });
  });
};
```

Then i ran the node server by nodemon server.js
Server successfully ran.
then, I try to get the data from the database using POST MAN Application.

So, I did like below,

**GET** method: localhost:3000/tasks

it successfully ran and it produced result.

like below,

```
[
  {
  "_id": "58ba4c9c03e10b16d140775f",
   "name": "Karthik",
   "__v": 0,
   "status": [
   "pending"
  ],
  "Created_date": "2017-03-04T05:11:56.590Z"
}]
```

My problem is here,

1)I didn't created the **__v**  and **id** fields here. Then why it is coming?
2)Then i need proper date format in **Created_date** field. like "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm". How to do it?

Help will be appreciated.Thank you.

**UPDATE**

When i try to install moment, following error occurs

> notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.  "_id": "58ba4c9c03e10b16d140775f"
```

this is the by default unique id created by mongodb for every document that you insert mongo will create an _id which is by default set as an index key.

For more reference you can read [advantage of _id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405720/whats-the-advantage-of-using-an-objectid-instead-of-a-plain-string)

```
2."__v": 0
```

The versionKey is a property set on each document when first created by Mongoose. This keys value contains the internal revision of the document. The versionKey option is a string that represents the path to use for versioning.

[open this for more details](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey)

```
3."Created_date": "2017-03-04T05:11:56.590Z"
```

Is the default format that mongodb Save date in. Mongodb Uses ISO format to store the date. If you want to save it that way you can store date in string format but or you can save in ISO format but when you are fetching the document you can use modules such as [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) to display the date in which ever format you want.

Comment: How to get rid of __v from json.?How to set the proper date of mine?

Comment: you can add do this at the time of inserting the data.

 new Schema({..}, { skipVersioning: { dontVersionMe: true } });
thing.dontVersionMe.push('hey');
thing.save(); // version is not incremented

Comment: or if you want dont want to get it when you are using retrieving the data you can use this Models.facilities.find(criteria, {__v:0}, options, callback); 

pass __v:0 in projection.

Comment: moment not installing on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Yes that's correct just you need to close that square bracket as well. And you can install npm module of moment.

Comment: I am having Ubuntu 16.04.  I need to install via terminal.  How to do it. ? I tried with your moment link using npm. But it gives os contradiction error.

Comment: just try npm install moment

Comment: which version of node and you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137312/discussion-between-shumi-gupta-and-ahamed).