# retrieve jsonObject from Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am implementing server related API using NodeJs and MongoDB with mongoose Schema based model. So My previous question was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595860/nodejs-with-mongodb-jsonformat-issue)

```
'use strict';


mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Task = mongoose.model('Tasks');

exports.list_all_tasks = function(req, res) {
  Task.find({}, function(err, task) {
    if (err){
      res.send(err);
    }
    // console.log('Web Server started, waiting for connections...'+task);
    res.json(task);
  });
};
```

When i run the server it returns the jsonArray like this,

```
 [
  {
   "_id": "58ba4c9c03e10b16d140775f",
   "name": "Noorul ahamed",
   "__v": 0,
   "status": [
   "pending"
  ],
   "Created_date": "2017-03-04T05:11:56.590Z"
 },
 ....
 ...
 ...
]
```

here my doubt is,

in that above code, task gives this kind of response. how do i get the every object in that task array? do i need to use for loop to get all object from that array? I am new to  NodeJs and MongoDB. I structured well server.Now I am stuck with this.? Help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
    // var myOwnObject = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', id: 'string',status:'string',createdDate:'String' });
    //      var myOwnObject = {};

    var dataArray;
    for (var i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
        var userObject = task[i];
        myOwnObject.name=userObject.name;
        myOwnObject.id=userObject._id;
        myOwnObject.status=userObject.status[0];
        myOwnObject.createdDate=userObject.Created_date;
        dataArray[i]=myOwnObject;
     }
    res.json(JSON.Stringify(dataArray));
```

**Error**

events.js:161
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
>       at /home/noorulhasan/todoListApi/api/controllers/todoListController.js:17:29
>       at model.Query. (/home/noorulhasan/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3433:16)
>       at /home/noorulhasan/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
>       at /home/noorulhasan/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>   [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

**UPDATE ERROR**
When i tried with myObject={}

events.js:161
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

> TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
>       at /home/noorulhasan/todoListApi/api/controllers/todoListController.js:21:25
>       at model.Query. (/home/noorulhasan/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3433:16)
>       at /home/noorulhasan/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
>       at /home/noorulhasan/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

**UPDATE**

I am getting this kind of output. how to get rid of '\' symbol.

`"[{\"name\":\"Ahamed\",\"id\":\"58bac0fc2cf0894f071e41c0\",\"createdDate\":\"2017-03-04T13:28:28.759Z\"}]`

I tried following way.

```
    var jsonData=JSON.stringify(dataArray);
    var updateJson = jsonData.replace('"\"', "");
    res.json(JSON.stringify(updateJson));
```

but it adds extra symbols like below,

`"\"[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Ahamed\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"58bac0fc2cf0894f071e41c0\\\",\\\"status\\\":\\\"pending\\\",\\\"createdDate\\\":\\\"2017-03-04T13:28:28.759Z\\\"}]\""`

Comment: Your `task` is just a normal array. You can access elements inside it like you would with any normal array. You can select a particular element with `task[n]` or use any kind of loop or iterator functions with it.

Comment: @JyotmanSingh thanks for your help. i tried the above way. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to `myOwnObject` being undefined. You need to initialise object before you can start setting their properties. The error you are getting mentions that

> Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

It means `myOwnObject` is not defined but you're trying to set `myOwnObject.name`.

Initialise your object like this -

```
var myOwnObject = {};
```

instead of

```
var myOwnObject;
```

Error should be gone now.

**Update** - For the second error -

The same thing as above is also true for arrays. Your `dataArray` is not initialised. You need to initialise it like this -

```
var dataArray = [];
```

**Update 2** -

You are getting the `\` in your output because you are converting your JSON output to a single string. To send the JSON array directly, remove the `JSON.stringify()` method. Send the response like this -

```
res.json(dataArray);
```

Comment: I am using Atom editer. is there any debugger tools available for my implementation. ? i can't able to trace the object. So, is there any means that will be helpful to me. thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have tried apm install atom-bugs command, and apm install atom-bugs-ui atom-bugs-syntax
for debugging. even it makes somewhat trouble.

Comment: Not sure about atom. I use intelliJ which has debugger built-in.

Comment: Share the link of ide please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137344/discussion-between-jyotman-singh-and-ahamed).